# iOS Chart Library : In Linechart , Legends are overlapping

Tags: ios, swift, mpandroidchart, ios-charts

I am using this chart library https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts in my application . I implemented the line chart from it, the legends are overlapping on each other . I am not sure what is wrong here , I did play with different attributes of the legends a lot but did not get it working fine at end . Here is the code for adding legends .

```
    ledgendEntries = [LegendEntry]()

    let legendEntry1 = LegendEntry(label: "Legend 1 Title", form: Legend.Form.circle, formSize: CGFloat.nan, formLineWidth: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashPhase: 1.0, formLineDashLengths: nil, formColor: UIColor.orange)

    let legendEntry2 = LegendEntry(label: "Legend 2 Title", form: Legend.Form.circle, formSize: CGFloat.nan, formLineWidth: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashPhase: 1.0, formLineDashLengths: nil, formColor: UIColor.orange)

    let legendEntry3 = LegendEntry(label: "Legend 3 Title", form: Legend.Form.circle, formSize: CGFloat.nan, formLineWidth: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashPhase: 1.0, formLineDashLengths: nil, formColor: UIColor.orange)

    ledgendEntries.append(legendEntry1)
    ledgendEntries.append(legendEntry2)
    ledgendEntries.append(legendEntry3)

    lineChartView.legend.entries = ledgendEntries
    lineChartView.legend.enabled = true
```

[image]

Comment: @ Bharat jagtap you have to add  visible range ' charts.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 3, maxXRange: 5)'

Comment: @Malleswari it has no effect , rather it is creeating a crash :-(

Comment: @BharatJagtap why you are adding legends array in line chart as it will take legends automatically from your line data ?

Comment: Facing same overlapping issue, were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @Molly I did a work around, don't use the legend instead add a label of your own at the bottom and show the values using attributed text . For now this is what I have done .

Comment: @Bharat exactly this is what I end up doing. Thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this exact same issue and found out that if you setup the legend BEFORE you set the chart's data the issue is fixed.